# Использование родительского метода при переопределении этого метода в дочернем классе в C++

Tags: c++, наследование, методы, переопределение

Пусть имеется 2-е структуры `A` и `B` (`B` унаследованна от `A`). В `A` имеется метод `f`, который переопределяется в `B`. При переопределении `f` внутри `B` хотелось бы использовать метод `f`, каким он был до переопределения. Как это можно сделать?

Функция `f` из `B` в коде, приведенном ниже, должна возвращать `x * 2` т.е. `4`.

```cpp
struct A {
    int x = 2;
    int f() {
        return x;
    }
};
struct B : public A {
    int f() {
        return *f до переопределения*() * 2;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого воспользуйтесь оператором `::` ([подробнее](https://ravesli.com/urok-159-vyzov-i-pereopredelenie-metodov-roditelskogo-klassa/#toc-2)):

```cpp
struct B : public A {
    int f() {
        return A::f() * 2;
    }
};
```